# How to post form with WWW::Mechanize (ajax)

Tags: ajax, perl, mechanize

I posted a few days ago about posting a form by changing the page size.  Can someone help with the steps.  I am including the dump of the form and the code I'm using to post it.  Here is the code to get the first page, which defaults to a page size of 30 players, and then from there I am going to post the form to change page size to 500.

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $url = "https://www.fangraphs.com/projections.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&type=steamer&team=0&lg=all&players=0";
$mech->get($url);
print Dumper($mech->forms());
```

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'default_charset' => 'UTF-8',
                 'enctype' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                 'accept_charset' => 'UNKNOWN',
                 'action' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'https://www.fangraphs.com/projections.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&type=steamer&team=0&lg=all&players=0')}, 'URI::https' ),
                 'method' => 'POST',
                 'attr' => {
                             'id' => 'form1',
                             'method' => 'post'
                           },
                 'inputs' => [
                               bless( {
                                        'readonly' => 1,
                                        '/' => '/',
                                        'value_name' => '',
                                        'value' => '',
                                        'name' => 'RadScriptManager1_TSM',
                                        'id' => 'RadScriptManager1_TSM',
                                        'type' => 'hidden'
                                      }, 'HTML::Form::TextInput' ),
                               bless( {
                                        '/' => '/',
                                        'value' => '30',
                                        'name' => 'ProjectionBoard1$dg1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$PageSizeComboBox',
                                        'readonly' => 'readonly',
                                        'value_name' => '',
                                        'type' => 'text',
                                        'class' => 'rcbInput radPreventDecorate',
                                        'id' => 'ProjectionBoard1_dg1_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_PageSizeComboBox_Input'
                                      }, 'HTML::Form::TextInput' ),
                               bless( {
                                        'tabindex' => '-1',
                                        'class' => 'rcbActionButton',
                                        'type' => 'button'
                                      }, 'HTML::Form::SubmitInput' ),
                               bless( {
                                        'readonly' => 1,
                                        '/' => '/',
                                        'value_name' => '',
                                        'name' => 'ProjectionBoard1_dg1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_ClientState',
                                        'id' => 'ProjectionBoard1_dg1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_ClientState',
                                        'type' => 'hidden'
                                      }, 'HTML::Form::TextInput' ),
                             ]
               }, 'HTML::Form' );
```

I then try to submit the form with the following:

```
$mech->submit_form(
    form_id => 'form1',
    with_fields => {
        name    => 'ProjectionBoard1$dg1$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$PageSizeComboBox',
        id      => 'ProjectionBoard1_dg1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_Input',
        value   => 500,
    },
);
```

but the response I get from the script is 'There is no form with the requested fields '

Comment: It should be `with_fields => { $field_name => $field_value }` **BUT** it tries to set`` `readonly` files (and it does not produce what you want anyway).

Comment: The field name and id  don't match the name and id of the form you received by your get req.

Answer (score 0):

try something like that:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $url = "https://www.fangraphs.com/projections.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&type=steamer&team=0&lg=all&players=0";
$mech->get($url);
$mech->set_fields( 
'RadScriptManager1_TSM' => '',
'ProjectionBoard1$dg1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$PageSizeComboBox' => '30'
'ProjectionBoard1_dg1_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_ClientState' => ''
);
$mech->submit;
```

set the form fields using the syntax 'FIELD_NAME' => 'VALUE' and then submit